# Notice of Credit Card Fraud via text on my phone someone responded how did they do it?

Tags: sms, fraud

I received a text alert from Capital One fraud alerting me of unusual activity someone replied to the text confirming the activity. I have an Iphone. How can they get access to my phone and what do I need to do to secure it? I've called Capital One and card is inactive my primary question is.. do I have some sort of malware on my phone?  Can I search it?  How do I secure my phone?  Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Which iPhone? How do you know they responded? Did you see their reply being sent from your iPhone or is it only the bank that told you they replied?

Comment: You're question is really unclear. You need to be very precise when explaining what you received and what happened to know for sure if this is a social engineering attack (just a trick meant to fool you into doing something) or something is actually wrong.

Comment: might just have been a wrong number, i've gotten angry and lovy texts from strangers

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone (assuming its relatively current) can perform SMS relaying, sending/receiving messages using the iMessage app, on other devices that are logged in to your account.  You should check your associated devices via the Apple web site to ensure there are no unknown devices listed and remove them if there are.

Assuming you are not using a jailbroken iPhone your apps should be safe, but to be sure you should review all the installed apps on your phone for any that were recently installed that you don't recognize.